# SASS string to "non string"

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass, node-sass

I have a scenario where I am using a JSON file in order to dynamically create SASS variables. The plugin ([Gulp-json-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-css)) can retain the map and array properties, but does not add quotations onto the map keys:

```
$palettes : ( white: #ffffff, grey: (lite: #aaaaaa, base: #999999, dark: #666666), black: #000000);
```

I am running into an issue where `map-get()` is not able to find the appropriate value if a quoted string is used for the parameter.

```
map-get($palettes, white) => #ffffff

map-get($palettes, "white") => null
--
Conclusion : (white != "white")
```

Is there anyway to change a quoted string into an "unquoted" string? I know what you're thinking, but `unquote()` doesn't work either:

```
$color : "white";
white == unquote($color) => false
```

I need a way to turn `"white"` into `white` in order to appropriately retrieve the correct value using the `map-get()` function.

**UPDATE / SOLUTION**

To whoever comes across this page and is looking for a solution, I ended up writing a function that will loop through a map and add quotes to it's keys:

```
@function quoteMapKeys( $map )
{
    $newMap : ();

    @each $key,$value in $map
    {
        @if type-of($value) == 'map'
        {
            $value : quoteMapKeys( $value );
        }

        $newMap : map-merge($newMap, (quote($key):$value));
    }

    @return $newMap;
}
```

```
$palettes : quoteMapKeys( $palettes );
```

Comment: Try using `#{white}`. If neither this nor `unquote()` works, you might open an issue on GitHub, since it shouldn't matter anyways, wether your string is quoted or not. You can additionally check your Sass version.

Comment: Yeah I've also tried interpolation as well. Keep in mind that the string is coming from a variable like my last example "unquote" example. I also sent a message to the author of "node-sass" to see if they had anything in mind.

Comment: I could then only suggest you to migrate to Dart Sass. This might help. Lib Sass was not updated in a long time

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually ended up finding a solution to my issue by writing a function that adds quotes to your map's keys.